# Viewing number of subscribed user for each Branch link

Tags: referrals, branch.io

I am using Branch SDK for track marketing and Referrals in my android app. Can i add a new column "Subscribed" in marketing section along with Total clicks and Total Installs.? If so how its possible.? if no, then how can i track number of users subscribed from each partner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're in the process of revamping the marketing tab to allow for custom events for each link, campaign, etc. In the mean time, you do custom conversion funnels by link by clicking on the stats button to the right of the link:

[image: stats]

Then scroll down to the bottom of the new page that opens. You can add a custom conversion funnel for 'install' -> 'subscribed'. This will show the exact number of folks that subscribed for each link. Make sure that your date selector includes the time frame you're interested in.

[image: conversion funnels]